# dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid losing focus

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have to refresh an Enhanced List as i have a "quick search" input field
that should update the list while you type. It does work fine, until I select one of the result rows. Then I move back to the input field and start typing but at that moment, the focus is lost and after every letter I have to click back to the input field.

Any method I found refreshing the grid sets the focus to the first header
cell. This means of course that my input field 
looses focus. I cannot type more than 1 char without refocusing the field
:-(

Any idea how to re-render a grid (or enhanced grid) without changing focus?

```
        gridtoc = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
            id: 'gridtocsearch',
            store: storetoc,
            structure: layout,
            class: 'grid',
            align: 'center',
            keepSelection: true,
            plugins: {
                filter: true
            }
        });
```

Thanks a lot, Monika

Answer (score 0):

can you try like

```
keepSelection:false
```

official document says

```
keepSelection
Defined by dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid
Whether keep selection after sort, filter, pagination etc.
```

***************** updated answer*****************
take a look at this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bnqkodup/520/

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, but it doesn't work. Still losing the focus.